# Swift: Navigating user after successfully signing up is not working?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a login and sign up view. If the user successfully logins they are taken to the homeMainView via NavigationLink, if they need to signup, the signup view is presented with a sheet. Authentication on both login and signup works fine but when the signup sheet is presented and the user successfully sign in, I can't get the view to Navlink to homeMainView from the presented sheet. The view navigate fine from the login view but not from the sign up. I tried couple of different methods but not success. Here is my code

```
struct LoginView: View {

@State private var email = ""
@State private var password = ""
@State private var formOffset: CGFloat = 0
@State private var presentSignupSheet = false
@State private var presentPasswordRecoverySheet = false
@State var isNavigationBarHidden: Bool = true

@State var isLinkActive = false // <- add here


var body: some View {
     NavigationView { // <- wrap in the `NavigationView`
    VStack(spacing: 40) {
        
        VStack {
            LCTextfield(value: self.$email, placeholder: "Email", icon: Image(systemName: "at"), onEditingChanged: { flag in
                withAnimation {
                    self.formOffset = flag ? -150 : 0
                }
            })
            LCTextfield(value: self.$password, placeholder: "Password", icon: Image(systemName: "lock"), isSecure: true)
            LCButton(text: "Login") {
                self.handleLogin(username: self.email, password: self.password)
            }
        }
        
        Button(action: {
            self.presentSignupSheet.toggle()
        }) {
          HStack {
            Text("Don't have an account? Sign up.").accentColor(Color.PrimaryColor)
              }
          }.sheet(isPresented: self.$presentSignupSheet) {
              SignupView()
          }
        
        Button(action: {
            self.presentPasswordRecoverySheet.toggle()
        }) {
          HStack {
            Text("Forgot your password?").accentColor(Color.PrimaryColor)
              }
          }.sheet(isPresented: self.$presentPasswordRecoverySheet) {
            RecoverPasswordView(presentPasswordRecoverySheet: self.$presentPasswordRecoverySheet)
          }

    }.padding().offset(y: self.formOffset)
        .background(Color.snowColor).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)


    .background( // add a hidden `NavigationLink` in the background
        NavigationLink(destination: homeMainView(), isActive: $isLinkActive) {
            EmptyView()
        }
        .hidden()
    )

    
  }.navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline) // optionally set title
   .navigationBarHidden(self.isNavigationBarHidden)
   .onAppear {
               self.isNavigationBarHidden = true
     }

}
```

when the signup is button is clicked it brings up the signup view

```
struct SignupView: View {

@State private var fname = ""
@State private var lname = ""

@State private var email = ""
@State private var password = ""
@State private var confirmedPassword = ""
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

@State private var formOffset: CGFloat = 0
@State var isLinkActive = false // <- add here

var body: some View {
    
    VStack(spacing: 40) {
   
        VStack {
            HStack {
                LCTextfield(value: self.$fname, placeholder: "First Name")
                LCTextfield(value: self.$lname, placeholder: "Last Name")
                
            }
            
            
            LCTextfield(value: self.$email, placeholder: "Email", icon: Image(systemName: "at"), onEditingChanged: { flag in
                withAnimation {
                    self.formOffset = flag ? -150 : 0
                }
                
            })
            LCTextfield(value: self.$password, placeholder: "Password", icon: Image(systemName: "lock"), isSecure: true)
            LCButton(text: "Sign up") {
                self.handleSignUp(username: self.email, password: self.password)
            }
        }
        
        Button(action: {
        }) {
          HStack {
            Text("Already have an account?").accentColor(Color.accentColor)
              }
          }
        
   }.padding().offset(y: self.formOffset)
    .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline) // optionally set title
           .navigationBarHidden(true)
           .background( // add a hidden `NavigationLink` in the background
               NavigationLink(destination: homeMainView(), isActive: $isLinkActive) {
                   EmptyView()
               }
               .hidden()
           )
    
    .background(Color.snowColor).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
  }



  func handleSignUp(username: String, password: String) {
         app.usernamePasswordProviderClient().registerEmail(email, password: password, completion: { (error) in
            // Completion handlers are not necessarily called on the UI thread.
            // This call to DispatchQueue.main.sync ensures that any changes to the UI,
        
       
                print("Signup successful!")
                
                
         
                
                // Registering just registers. Now we need to sign in, but we can reuse the existing username and password.

                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                LoginView().handleLogin(username: self.email, password: self.password)
                self.isLinkActive = true // <- activate the `NavigationLink`

            }
        })
    }
```

what is the best way to navigate the user to the homeMainView once they have successfully signup?

Comment: Does the tutorial you took it from not work?

Comment: @pawello2222 I took some of it from a tutorial and built the rest. The tutorial part, LCTextfield, works as expected.

Comment: Assuming you used the [tutorial](https://liquidcoder.com/swiftui-onboarding-screen/) I think of, you can find its source code [here](https://github.com/liquidcoder1/OnboardingScreen).